# Installing gems with no network

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu, rubygems

I have to install several gem files on a machine that does NOT have an internet connection. To do this, I imported the packages from a machine that is connected to the internet and copied the files to the offline machine. I followed this [guide](https://help.rubygems.org/kb/rubygems/installing-gems-with-no-network) for the installation, but it is deprecated. In fact, the result is as follows:

```
gem install --force --local *.gem
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem '*.gem' (>= 0) in any repository
```

My question is: how can I install these 20/30 different gems without internet? Is there another way?

Thank you!

**Update:**
I tried again folder by folder to install the gems, first with "gem build" and then "gem install".
The result:

```
WARNING:  Unable to pull data from 'https://rubygems.org/': Errno::ENETUNREACH: Failed to open TCP connection to rubygems.org:443 (Network is unreachable - connect(2) for "rubygems.org" port 443) (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
1 gem installed
```

Could be a proxy problem?

Comment: does this help at all: https://bundler.io/man/bundle-cache.1.html

Comment: The method seems to be still working. Are you inside the local folder where gems have been imported?

Comment: Are you using bundler? If so, you can simply "vendor" the gems into a local directory on a machine connected to the internet, and then copy that directory to the target machine. For example, `bundle install --path=gems`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.
Basically 2 Problems:
If i wanted to install the gems from the gem folder, i had first to run the build and after the install.
But i could also install the gems placed inside the cache folder, and inside this folder run directly "gem install --force --local".
Thank you all of you for your answers.